# как загрузить текстуру в opengl?

Tags: opengl

Я только начал изучать opengl. Дошёл до темы с текстурами. Для загрузки изображения использовал библиотку stb_image. То есть сначала:

`unsigned char* data = stbi_load("container.jpg", &width, &height, &nrChannels, 0);`

а потом:

`glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);`

После этого картинка, которую я взял из туториала, прекрасно вывелась на экран. Позже я захотел вывести любую другую картинку из интернета. Я скачал 2 картинки, которые так же как и первая были в фрмате `jpg`. Помимо этого во всех трё случаях `nrChannels` возвращает число 3. Но несмотря на это ни одна из моих картинок не смогла нормально вывестисть так же как и первая. В одном случае изображение почемуто выводилсь чёрно-белое и слегка скошенное, а во втором вообще была какая-то каша из пикселей.

**Вопрос**: Почему так произошло, и как мне использовать в качестве текстуры любое изображение, которое я захочу ?

Comment: Проверьте, может быть важно, чтобы размер картинки в пикселях был степенью двойки? (32, 64, 128, 256, 512, и тд..)

Comment: @Kromster нет. Нашёл одну пикчу с разрешение 680x460 и она прекрасно вывелась

Comment: @Kromster Я нашёл решение! перед  `glTexImage2D` нужно использовать `glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);` и тогда всё прекрасно работает. Правда я понятия не имею, что делает эта функция. Судя по документации задаёт какое-то выравнивание, но что за выравнивание я не понимаю